# class in the included html not able to access function in parent file html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a mainfile.html with the following content

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("d.html"); 

      $(".alertclass").click(function(){
         alert('some c load action');
      });

    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
    <a class="alertclass" href="javascript:void(0);"> parent clicks heret </a>
    <br/>
     <div id="includedContent" ></div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

and my "d.html" file has content

```
<div> <br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alertclass">the child clicks here</a>
</div>
```

but the class "alertclass" does not seem to work when i click on the link in the included content from the child's page. is there a way to make it work for the included child page too?

P.S. - i tried to use "live" but, it throws an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'"

I am looking for a solution apart from "live". Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`live` threw the `no method` error because it was removed from jQuery in version 1.9. It has been superceded by using `on` with a delegate selector.

Your problem is because you are attempting to attach the event to `.alertClass` before the content has finished loading. Try placing the event hook in the callback of `load`:

```
$("#includedContent").load("d.html", function() {
    $(".alertclass").click(function(){
        alert('some c load action');
    });
});
```

Alternatively as I mentioned, you could use `on` with a delegate selector:

```
$("#includedContent").load("d.html");
$(document).on('click', ".alertclass", function(){
    alert('some c load action');
});
```

Comment: The 'on' suggestion make it available only to the child class. The first one is close to what i was looking for,

Comment: Cool, the Alternative you provided is what i was looking for. because, if i use the first one, i would have to do it for any other page i would be loading, and if all of them contain the class i am using.